# Conflict between MySQL and mail Java libraries

Tags: java, mysql, email, classpath

I have a problem with Java libraries. I'm using javax.mail and mysql-connector.
While compiling I don't have any problems, but if I try to execute the program with sudo:

```
$sudo java Server -jar mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar
```

It gives me this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)
    at dbConnect.dbQuery(dbConnect.java:192)
    at Server.main(Server.java:39)
```

while if I try to execute it without sudo:

```
$java Server -jar mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar
```

It gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/internet/AddressException
    at dbConnect.registration(dbConnect.java:161)
    at dbConnect.splitUsrPass(dbConnect.java:87)
    at dbConnect.dbQuery(dbConnect.java:196)
    at Server.main(Server.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.internet.AddressException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 4 more
```

I can understand why it doesn't work without administrator privileges (I guess the mail library requires them) but it seems strange to me that it won't find the MySQL library if I give it the administrator privileges.

Does anyone know if this is a known issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to run something with Java on the command line, you have two options:

Run a class: `java MyClass`
Run a jar: `java -jar MyJar.jar`

What you are trying to do is both, which will result in the `-jar`-part will be ignored.

I'm guessing that what you want to do is run the class `Server`, with the `MySQL`-jar on the classpath. The correct command will then be:

```
java Server -cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar
```

You could also add the directory containing the `MySQL`-jar to the `CLASSPATH` environment variable. The reason you get different error messages when using `sudo` and not is probably because the `root` user has a different `CLASSPATH` than your user (your user lacks the `javax.mail`-jar on the classpath, while `root` has it.)